# SQLAlchemy is not getting created in flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I get error "RuntimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app. Import and use that instance instead" for below piece of code. Although I have not created this instance before

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqllite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can check for any other instances of SQLAlchemy in your codebase. Make sure that you are not creating another instance of SQLAlchemy before the code snippet you provided. Double-check your imports and any other parts of your code that might be creating an instance of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I don't think I  have created instance already. To make it more clear, I have edited my question and included all imports.

Answer (score 0):

This is the data base configuration in fastapi

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine   
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base   
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
 
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqllite:///test.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False} )

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

And the database db are connect  when you you add this section

```
models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) 

def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```